# Unlock/Enable adjacent dropdown on user's current choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form with three dropdowns on a html webpage with the usual options of:

- 1st dropdown (A) has the options 1 to 6, as well as 'not set'.
- 2nd dropdown (B) has the options 1 to 7, as well as 'not set'.
- 3rd dropdown (C) has the options 1 to 6, as well as 'not set'.

I would like to add a set of rules to the adjacent dropdown only making it enabled if the user has selected an option from the previous dropdown: e.g: a user can only select an option from dropdown B if they have selected from dropdown A.

Also I would like to apply a set of rules to modify the options:

- if B is 1, C can only contain 1 or 'not set'
- if B is 4, C can only contain 1 to 5, or 'not set'

How would I do this with either JavaScript or Jquery?

Comment: Posting some code (of what you have, or what you've tried) would be helpful.

Comment: S.O. is for helping programmers solve coding problems, not for handing them answers.

Comment: All I wanted was some sort of direction on the route to take... was playing with this so far for jquery: `$('#b').change(function (event) {
    if ($('#b').val() === 1) {
        $("#c option[value=all]").remove();
    }
});`

Comment: I managed to do this using the example given in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695787/adding-another-dropdown-list-to-a-form-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact code, but you don't apply rules in the adjacent dropdown. You apply rules in the active dropdown that enable or disable the adjacent dropdown.

In your case, dropdown A needs to have an "OnChange" event (or some similar event) that enables or disables dropdown B (using the DOM) based on the selection the user makes in dropdown A.  Same thing for dropdown B: when the user makes a selection, a function called by dropdown B either enables or disables dropdown C based on what the user just selected in dropdown B.

Comment: You can also program one master controller function that is called from dropdown A's OnChange event AND dropdown B's OnChange event. It can read values from A and B, and determine whether to enable/disable dropdowns B and C (or make any other changes to them that you like.)